# Best practice to deal with Docker images ARM/AMD compatibility issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building Docker images of a web app locally on my Mac and then running them via Docker Compose on a remote server that's running Ubuntu AMD64. I get an error that the platform isn't compatible, and I'm curious what's the best practice in real production environments to tackle this issue.

Do I support 2 image types? Do I specify something in the Dockerfile that allows the image to run on all platforms?

I was able to bypass this by re-building the image on the remote server, but not sure if this is a best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/

Comment: Have both processor-architecture nodes in your CI system, and have build jobs that build both architectures' images.